# general lag in time series panel data

Tags: r, time-series, lag

I have a dataset akin to this

```
User    Date        Value
A       2012-01-01  4
A       2012-01-02  5   
A       2012-01-03  6
A       2012-01-04  7
B       2012-01-01  2
B       2012-01-02  3   
B       2012-01-03  4
B       2012-01-04  5
```

I want to create a lag of `Value`, respecting `User`.

```
User    Date        Value   Value.lag
A       2012-01-01  4       NA
A       2012-01-02  5       4
A       2012-01-03  6       5
A       2012-01-04  7       6
B       2012-01-01  2       NA
B       2012-01-02  3       2   
B       2012-01-03  4       3
B       2012-01-04  5       4
```

I've done it very inefficiently in a loop

```
df$value.lag1<-NA
levs<-levels(as.factor(df$User))
levs
  for (i in 1:length(levs)) {
    temper<- subset(df,User==as.numeric(levs[i]))
    temper<- rbind(NA,temper[-nrow(temper),])  
df$value.lag1[df$User==as.numeric(as.character(levs[i]))]<- temper
      }
```

But this is very slow. I've looked at using `by` and `tapply`, but not figured out how to make them work.

I don't think XTS or TS will work because of the User element.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I think the `plm` package has an implementation for this type of data.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use `ddply`: it cuts a data.frame into pieces and transforms each piece.

```
d <- data.frame( 
  User = rep( LETTERS[1:3], each=10 ),
  Date = seq.Date( Sys.Date(), length=30, by="day" ),
  Value = rep(1:10, 3)
)
library(plyr)
d <- ddply( 
  d, .(User), transform,
  # This assumes that the data is sorted
  Value = c( NA, Value[-length(Value)] ) 
)
```

Comment: Following http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1296646/how-to-sort-a-dataframe-by-columns-in-r sorting can be done with `arrange()`

Comment: This is the best solution that worked for me ! Could you show how do we use the same process, but to lead, instead of lag? I have a panel data where the time points are not uniform for all the participants.

Answer (score 8):

I think the easiest way, especially considering doing further analysis, is to convert your data frame to `pdata.frame` class from `plm` package.

After the conversion from `diff()` and `lag()` operators can be used to create panel differences and lags.

```
df<-pdata.frame(df,index=c("id","date"))  
df<-transform(df, l_value=lag(value,1))
```

Comment: elegant answer -- using just lag() to calculate the time lag as a new variable after it's converted to a pdata.frame also works!

Answer (score 2):

For a panel without missing obs this is an intuitive solution:

```
df <- data.frame(id = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2), 
                 date = c(1992, 1993, 1991, 1990, 1994, 1992, 1991), 
                 value = c(4.1, 4.5, 3.3, 5.3, 3.0, 3.2, 5.2))

df<-df[with(df, order(id,date)), ]  # sort by id and then by date
df$l_value=c(NA,df$value[-length(df$value)]) # create a new var with data displaced by 1 unit
df$l_value[df$id != c(NA, df$id[-length(df$id)])] =NA # NA data with different current and lagged id.
df

id date value l_value
4  1 1990   5.3      NA
3  1 1991   3.3     5.3
1  1 1992   4.1     3.3
2  1 1993   4.5     4.1
5  1 1994   3.0     4.5
7  2 1991   5.2      NA
6  2 1992   3.2     5.2
```

Answer (score 2):

I stumbled over a similar problem and wrote a function.

```
#df needs to be a structured balanced paneldata set sorted by id and date
#OBS the function deletes the row where the NA value would have been.

df <- data.frame(id = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2,2,2,2), 
                 date = c(1992, 1993, 1991, 1990, 1994, 1992, 1991
                          ,1994,1990,1993), 
                 value = c(4.1, 4.5, 3.3, 5.3, 3.0, 3.2, 5.2,5.3,3.4,5.6))
# sort paneldata set
library(dplyr)
df<-arrange(df,id,date)

#Function
# a=df
# b=colname of variable/variables that you want to lag
# q=number of lag years
# t=colname of date/time column
retraso<-function(a,b,q,t){

  sto<-max(as.numeric(unique(a[[t]])))
  sta<-min(as.numeric(unique(a[[t]])))

  yo<-a[which(a[[t]]>=(sta+q)),]

  la<-function(a,d,t,sto,sta){


    ja<-data.frame(a[[d]],a[[t]])
    colnames(ja)<-c(d,t)


    ja<-ja[which(ja[[t]]<=(sto-q)),1]
    return(ja)
  }

  for (i in 1:length(b)){

    yo[[b[i]]] <-la(a,b[i],t,sto,sta)

    }
    return(yo)

  }

#lag df 1 year
df<-retraso(df,"value",1,"date")
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have gaps in the time variable , do

```
df %>% group_by(User) %>% mutate(value_lag = lag(value, order_by =Date)
```

If you do have gaps in the time variable, see this answer
https://stackoverflow.com/a/26108191/3662288

Answer (score 0):

Similarly, you could use `tapply`

```
# Create Data
user = c(rep('A',4),rep('B',4))
date = rep(seq(as.Date('2012-01-01'),as.Date('2012-01-04'),1),2)
value = c(4:7,2:5) 
df = data.frame(user,date,value)
# Get lagged values
df$value.lag = unlist(tapply(df$value, df$user, function(x) c(NA,x[-length(df$value)])))
```

The idea is exactly the same: take value, split it by user, and then run a function on each subset. The unlist brings it back into vector format.

Answer (score 0):

Provided the table is ordered by User and Date, this can be done with `zoo`. The trick is not to specify an index at this point.

```
library(zoo)
df <-read.table(text="User Date Value
A 2012-01-01 4
A 2012-01-02 5
A 2012-01-03 6
A 2012-01-04 7
B 2012-01-01 2
B 2012-01-02 3
B 2012-01-03 4
B 2012-01-04 5", header=TRUE, as.is=TRUE,sep = " ")

out <-zoo(df)

Value.lag <-lag(out,-1)[out$User==lag(out$User)]
res <-merge.zoo(out,Value.lag)
res <-res[,-(4:5)]  # to remove extra columns

  User.out Date.out   Value.out Value.Value.lag
1 A        2012-01-01 4         <NA>           
2 A        2012-01-02 5         4              
3 A        2012-01-03 6         5              
4 A        2012-01-04 7         6              
5 B        2012-01-01 2         <NA>           
6 B        2012-01-02 3         2              
7 B        2012-01-03 4         3              
8 B        2012-01-04 5         4
```

Answer (score 0):

The *collapse* package now available on CRAN provides the most general C/C++ based solution to (fully-identified) panel-lags, leads, differences and growth rates / log differences. It has the generic functions `flag`, `fdiff` and `fgrowth` and associated lag / lead, difference and growth operators `L`, `F`, `D` and `G`. So to lag a panel dataset, it is sufficient to type:

```
L(data, n = 1, by = ~ idvar, t = ~ timevar, cols = 4:8)
```

which means: Compute 1 lag of columns 4 through 8 of `data`, identified by `idvar` and `timevar`. Multiple ID and time-variables can be supplied i.e. `~ id1 + id2`, and sequences of lags and leads can also be computed on each column (i.e. `n = -1:3` computes one lead and 3 lags). The same thing can also be done more programmatically with `flag`:

```
flag(data[4:8], 1, data$idvar, data$timevar)
```

Both of these options compute below 1 millisecond on typical datasets (<30,000 obs.). Large data performance is similar to data.tables shift. Similar programming applies to differences `fdiff / D` and growth rates `fgrowth / G`. These functions are all S3 generic and have vector / time-series, matrix / ts-matrix, data.frame, as well as `plm::pseries` and `plm::pdata.frame` and `grouped_df` methods. Thus they can be used together with `plm` classes for panel data and with dplyr.