# Create lagged variable in unbalanced panel data in R

Tags: r, data.table, dplyr, panel-data

I'd like to create a variable containing the value of a variable in the previous year within a group.

```
     id   date        value
1     1   1992          4.1  
2     1     NA          4.5  
3     1   1991          3.3  
4     1   1990          5.3  
5     1   1994          3.0  
6     2   1992          3.2  
7     2   1991          5.2
```

`value_lagged` should be missing when the previous year is missing within a group - either because it is the first date within a group (as in row 4, 7), or because there are year gaps in the data (as in row 5). Also, `value_lagged` should be missing  when the current time is missing (as in row 2).

This gives:

```
     id   date    value    value_lagged  
1     1   1992      4.1             3.3
2     1     NA      4.5              NA
3     1   1991      3.3             5.3
4     1   1990      5.3              NA
5     1   1994      3.0              NA
6     2   1992      3.2             5.2
7     2   1991      5.2              NA
```

---

For now, in R, I use the `data.table` package

```
 DT = data.table(id    = c(1,1,1,1,1,2,2),
                 date  = c(1992,NA,1991,1990,1994,1992,1991),
                 value = c(4.1,4.5,3.3,5.3,3.0,3.2,5.2)
                )
 setkey(DT, id, date)
 DT[, value_lagged := DT[J(id, date-1), value], ]
 DT[is.na(date), value_lagged := NA, ]
```

It's fast but it seems somewhat error prone to me. I'd like to know if there are better alternatives using `data.table`, `dplyr`, or any other package. Thanks a lot!

---

In `Stata`, one would do:

```
    tsset id date
    gen value_lagged=L.value
```

Comment: unless you specifically want rows with a missing **value** to not have a matching lagged value, you likely meant to use `is.na(date)` not `is.na(value)`

Comment: @Matthew seems like you already have a decent solution - what exactly do you want to improve about it?

Comment: My solution seems somewhat convoluted and error prone to me - but maybe because I'm new to R. And even it is a decent solution, there might be even simpler ways to do it! In any case, it's an important question (at least for stata users), so I thought there should be a definitive question/answer on stack overflow about it.

Comment: Here's a slight rewrite of your final two steps, that's perhaps slightly less error prone (because you're not repeating `DT` multiple times), but I don't really see what else you want besides having a function that's specifically designed to do what you want (which what your stata solution really is): `DT[J(id, date + 1, val = value), val_lag := i.val][is.na(date), val_lag := NA]`

Comment: Thanks! Wait why does not it give rows with date==1995?

Comment: This is so weird. So `D1=DT[J(id, date + 1, val = value)]`, `D1[, val_lag:=val]` does not give the same than  `DT[J(id, date + 1, val = value)][, val_lag:=val]` ?

Comment: Well, I understand now -even though it's still a bit puzzling. Would you know if one of the syntax between `DT[J(id, date + 1, val = value), val_lag := i.val]` and  `DT[,value_lagged :=DT[list(id,date-1),value],]` preferable for what data.table does? Or are they completely equivalent?

Comment: @Matthew they are not equivalent `DT[J(...), a := b]` does the assignments for the matching portion of `DT` from the merge, whereas `DT[J(...)]` may be larger or smaller than `DT` itself.

Comment: the `DT[J(...), a := b]` syntax is better in that it avoids using the `data.table` name twice, which can be a source of errors; it's also going to be a tiny bit faster, but that's probably irrelevant for any task

Comment: You should post yours as the answer (for data.table), as that's the way to go about it. There's no copy being made there at all, which is also a requirement from your Q.

Comment: @eddi actually I've recently realized your answer does not work in case there are no missing dates and no corresponding observation within each group (for instance -8 in my example)

Comment: @Arun wrote another method as an answer!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Create a function `tlag`, which lags a vector given a vector of times,  and use it within groups defined by `id`

```
library(dplyr)
tlag <- function(x, n = 1L, time) { 
  index <- match(time - n, time, incomparables = NA)
  x[index]
}

df %>% group_by(id) %>% mutate(value_lagged = tlag(value, 1, time = date))
```

Comment: `N=2e6L` is quite small. 0.1 vs 0.23 seconds isn't that impressive.. Could you please try on `2e7L` or even `2e8L`?

Comment: It's not impressive indeed. The point was really to have a more readable solution, and it turns out that there is no performance cost at 2e6. I've just runned the test : lag is still *slightly* faster at 1e7, but pure data.table is twice faster at 1e8

Comment: The problem with *readability* is that it is not a proper measure; varies from one to another. I very much like the pure data.table solution, for example :).

Comment: Readability varies from one person to the next, but that does not mean it's not a proper measure, right? Don't you agree that, for a colleague who browses my code, the lag solution is clearer to read? What about confusing -1 and -1?

Comment: Would you post data.table's solution as an answer? I'd suppress it from my question, so that people would see three different answers for creating lagged variables

Comment: I don't think that's necessary. You've shown the solution as your attempt (which you felt could be improved - hence the question) and have posted a version which suits you better. And it's a great answer (I +1'd it already).

Comment: This is good and I upvoted it, but there's no reason to go defining a custom lag function with a dozen major packages already containing one and n-time-period lags.

Answer (score 11):

I'd probably tackle this using a join:

```
library(dplyr)

df <- data.frame(
  id = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2), 
  date = c(1992, NA, 1991, 1990, 1994, 1992, 1991), 
  value = c(4.1, 4.5, 3.3, 5.3, 3.0, 3.2, 5.2)
)


last_year <- df %>% 
  filter(!is.na(date)) %>%
  mutate(date = date + 1, lagged_value = value, value = NULL)

df %>%
  left_join(last_year)
#> Joining by: c("id", "date")
#>   id date value lagged_value
#> 1  1 1992   4.1          3.3
#> 2  1   NA   4.5           NA
#> 3  1 1991   3.3          5.3
#> 4  1 1990   5.3           NA
#> 5  1 1994   3.0           NA
#> 6  2 1992   3.2          5.2
#> 7  2 1991   5.2           NA
```

Answer (score 8):

Using `1.9.5`, where joins don't need keys to be set, this can be done as follows:

```
require(data.table) # v1.9.5+
DT[!is.na(date), value_lagged := 
         .SD[.(id = id, date = date - 1), value, on = c("id", "date")]]
#    id date value value_lagged
# 1:  1 1992   4.1          3.3
# 2:  1   NA   4.5           NA
# 3:  1 1991   3.3          5.3
# 4:  1 1990   5.3           NA
# 5:  1 1994   3.0           NA
# 6:  2 1992   3.2          5.2
# 7:  2 1991   5.2           NA
```

It's a variation of your idea. The trick is to use `is.na()` directly in `i` and use `.SD` in `j` instead of `DT`. I've used `on=` syntax, but the same idea can of course be done by setting keys as well.  .

Comment: Hi! With data.table 1.9.5, installed 11-sep-2015, this gives the error "Error in `[.data.table`(.SD, .(id = id, date = date - 1), value, on = c("id",  : 
  unused argument (on = c("id", "date"))"

Comment: @JBJ Use `remove.packages()` to uninstall, reinstall and try again.

Answer (score 0):

An elegant and fast general solution to computations on irregular time series and unbalanced panels is now offered by the `collapse` package with the functions `flag`, `fdiff` and `fgrowth`. See a general answer for lagging an unbalanced panel [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38245975/dplyr-custom-lag-function-for-irregular-time-series/68330161#68330161).

Now in your specific application there is an additional rare fact that the panel is not only unbalanced, but you have a missing value in your time variable which means you don't know the time period when a record was observed. In such cases just applying `collapse::flag` won't do, but you could generate a new id variable that places the missing value in a separate group with `collapse::seqid`. So my solution would be:

```r
library(collapse)  
DF = data.frame(id    = c(1,1,1,1,1,2,2),
                date  = c(1992,NA,1991,1990,1994,1992,1991),
                value = c(4.1,4.5,3.3,5.3,3.0,3.2,5.2))

settransform(DF, l_value = flag(value, 1, g = seqid(date, order(id, date)), t = date))
DF
#>   id date value l_value
#> 1  1 1992   4.1     3.3
#> 2  1   NA   4.5      NA
#> 3  1 1991   3.3     5.3
#> 4  1 1990   5.3      NA
#> 5  1 1994   3.0      NA
#> 6  2 1992   3.2     5.2
#> 7  2 1991   5.2      NA
```

<sup>Created on 2021-07-10 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

I am quite confident that this is still faster than `data.table`, but I have not tested this. Again this data is rather odd, for most cases where the panel is unbalanced but the records are all identified by id and time, a simple `flag(value, 1, id, as.integer(date))` will do fine and be striking fast. Note that you get efficiency gains by ensuring that the time variable is integer, as `flag` will coerce non-integer time variables to factor, which could also get rid of the irregularity.